# INODES - Work around?

Tags: php, mysql, file, inode

So, my hosting service has a limit of INODES on my server (index nodes). Each directory/file = 1 INODE. This might be a problem in the future as I want to implement file-sharing into my website. Couldn't I theoretically store the data of files into a MySQL database, then pull the data when a user requests a download? If this is possible, how would I do this in PHP?

**A MySQL Skeleton:**

```
TABLE: Files
ROWS: id, filename, data
```

Comment: How many files are you hosting? Some hosts disallow file sharing sites expressly in their TOS. It is worth investigating.

Comment: If you're storing so many files that you're going to break your INODE limit, I can guarantee you that your mysql database of files will probably break some other rule as well.

Comment: What kind of a limit? How many?

Comment: It's against my TOS, oh well :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't start storing stuff in the database *just* because of a restriction like this - there are serious downsides to the approach.

If you really expect your numbers to exceed what the provider allows anytime soon, change providers and/or rent a private server.

Most of the things discussed in this famous SO question:

[Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

apply to all file formats.